# Switch User over Sign out

Tags: usability, interaction-design, ux-designer

Do you think "switch user" option can be a great feature for a user having multiple account in sites like gmail rather than sign out option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that users have multiple accounts on your webpage. I am not talking about tracking it separately. I am asking that is it a official stand of the brand, that multiple accounts are encouraged? When you officially incorporate a workflow in your system, it is like saying you approve of it. (Reddit knows that people frequently have throwaway accounts on their site, but account switcher is not something that is readily provided. You need plug ins like RES to enrich the functionality.)

I know how [GMail does it](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1721977?hl=en). There is a thought of business plus personal accounts behind going that way. Google is very much into enterprise these days and this is one way to capture more possible markets. Even then they have not touched the traditional sign out button. It still exists. Allowing user to switch is an added option.

Another known system that does so is the OS. Windows offers switching accounts, when it is possible to have more than one people using a single system. Even their business case is different from Google, and they have definite reasons to add a switch option. If you notice, they have not taken the sign out / log off button out, yet.

To summarize, if your business officially supports having multiple accounts, you can think of including switch user as an additional option, but I would not touch sign out in the process.

Answer (score 0):

As the process of switching users is normally to sign out and then sign in again, I would stick with "Sign Out" and show a sign in form or link on the "You have been signed out" page.

Having "Switch User" in place of "Sign Out" may confuse some users, who just want to sign out.

Would love to see an A/B test if anyone has one.